# Returning An Object From an Asynchronous Operation

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am loading a CSV file from an external (web) source using PapaParse, which is constructed as an array contained within an object. This array is constructed as follows:

```
hazard: "Pepe"
impact: "PeepoLaugh"
issued: "11A Sunday"
person: "Pepe"
phenom: "Sadge"
polyid: 1
summary: "Lots of Text"
timing: "1P-4P Sunday"
```

The relevant functions to execute this process are as follows:

```
function handleParsedData(data) {
            console.log('Parsed data:', data);
            return data;
        }
     function downloadCSV(callback) {
        Papa.parse("/oath/to/file.txt", {
            download: true, 
            header: true,
            delimiter: "|",
            dynamicTyping:
            complete: function(results) {
                var parsedData = results.data;
                handleParsedData(results.data);
                callback(parsedData);
            }
        });
     }
     function exportedCSV() {
        parsed = downloadCSV(function(parsedData) {
            console.log(parsedData);
            return parsedData
        });
     }
     var exports = exportedCSV();
     console.log(exports);
```

Upon inspecting the console log messages, I can verify that the callback function downloadCSV works correctly, which triggers a console message of this object and its array from the function handleParsedData call. To double check that this works properly, I also verified a second console message of the identical object and its array contained inside the function exportedCSV call.

My problem extends to using this object and its array outside of this function. I've assigned a variable exports, which is attached to the exportedCSV call. When I inspect this variable in the console log, it returns as undefined. What steps can I take to use this array outside of the function?

Comment: your exportedcsv function needs a callback like downloadcsv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your `downloadCSV()` to an async function and use it with `await` or `then()` to get your parsed result:

```js
async function downloadCSV() {
  return new Promise((complete, error) => {
    Papa.parse("/oath/to/file.txt", {
        download: true, 
        header: true,
        delimiter: "|",
        dynamicTyping: ???,
        complete: result => complete(result.data),
        error
    });
  });
}

(async()=>{
  var exports = await downloadCSV();
  console.log(exports);
})();

// or

downloadCSV().then(exports => console.log(exports));
```

Comment: as they are already using callbacks, either a callback or .then would avoid having to async all the way back up the call stack

Comment: @mattrichards yes, `then()` could be more appropriate, added an example

Comment: This is in line with what I'm trying to achieve, I appreciate your prompt response to the question!

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev its a shame these questions get closed, because they usually reveal some nugget of wisdom, you both should join us on the javascript chat

Comment: I'm very much a rookie to JavaScript and was thrust immediately into figuring out asynchronous functions. Let's just say this is baptism by fire, any chat that can help me learn more wisdom like this would be very appreciated!

Comment: baptism by fire sounds a bit harsh hahaha we're more chilled in the chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript